# Bootstrap Flexbox Not Properly Aligning Rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to align three divs in bootstrap flexbox as rows, but they keep being aligned vertically instead of horizontally. I've been very circumspect with the code, so it does not appear to be a syntax error. Why would divs align vertically instead of horizontally if class "d-flex flex-row" is set and their size isn't too large?

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
            <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/custom.css">        
    
        <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
        <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
      </head>
      <body>
    
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row my-flex-container">
                <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">1</div>
                <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">2</div>
                <div class="p-2 my-flex-item">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
            
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Because you are using bootstrap 3

Comment: you have included bootstrap 3 while flex classes is for bootstrap 4

Comment: oh. sorry, dumb mistake. thank you.